# CurVe template \subrubric does not reset the year

Tags: curve-class

Below is the snippet from the CurVe CV template. In the below image, I want the year to show for Poster too. I expected `\subrubric` to reset the year, but it did not do so. How do I get a year entry for "Poster title 1".

```
\begin{rubric}{Conferences}
\subrubric{Talk}

\entry*[2022]%
    \textbf{Talk title 1}
    \par Institute.
    \par Talk on "Title"

\subrubric{Poster}

\entry*[2022]%
    \textbf{Poster title 1}
    \par Institute.
    \par Poster on "Title"
```

[image]

**First edit**

Tried the suggestion by @DaiBowen. It gives the error "Misplaced \noalign." The alignment is a bit off b/w 2022 and 2020.

[image]

Comment: This is the CV templeate [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being triggered by the [`curve`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/curve) class option `skipsamekey` which avoids repeating a key if it matches the previous key.
This is not the default of [`curve`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/curve) and can be disabled by omitting the `skipsamekey`.
However, the curveball is that the previous key is remembered across different `\subrubric`s, apparently without any interface to change this behaviour.

On a local basis we can prevent any entry's key being skipped by putting

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\@previouskey{}
\makeatother
```

so it will issue a key even if it matches.  For the first `\entry` under a `\subrubric` this should go before the `\subrubric` or it may need to be inserted as

```
\noalign{\makeatletter
\gdef\@previouskey{}
\makeatother}
```

We can also patch the `\subrubric` command to always reset the `\@previouskey` automatically by putting

```
\patchcmd{\subrubric}{\gdef\@nextentry{}}{\gdef\@nextentry{}\gdef\@previouskey{}}{}{}
```

in the preamble.

As one `subrubric` ending on the same key as the next starts is relatively unlikely, it might make sense to stick to manually clearing `\@previouskey` as necessary rather than relying on patching another macro.

Comment: Hi @DaiBowen, Tried your suggestion. I have edited my post with your suggestion. Please check.

Comment: @WhySoSerious for the first entry in a `\subrubric` then `\gdef\@previouskey` needs to come before `\subrubric` or be given in a `\noalign{}`.  Between consecutive `\entry`s under the same `\subrubric` this is fine.

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked like a charm.